# Separating lots of polygons connected by single vertex into individual polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon

I've been given a shapefile where lots of polygons are connected by a single vertex.

I've included an image which shows when you select 1 polygon it selects lots as they are all connected and overlapping in some places.

How can I separate the polygons in ArcMap?

[image]

Comment: thise line should not exist, there was probably an issue with the export. Try "repair geometry" first (on a copy of the file), then "multipart to single part". If this doesn't work, it will be difficult imho

Comment: What software was used to produce this shapefile?

Comment: That data is corrupt, and therefore you don't have a shapefile, just a set of files with suffixes that have the same naming as a shapefile.   Your data provider should correct the data to be conformant to the polygon rules in the shapefile specification.

Comment: No luck with the repair/multipart. This data was provided by a public service GIS department but then was manipulated by someone else.

Comment: Then *your* provider is the *someone else*. Either they need to fix it or give you the original data.